# Google Protocol Buffers Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, variant

I have the following method:

```
- (void)sendProtoToServer:(SampleMessage *)protoToSend {
   NSData *d = [protoToSend data];
   int s = [protoToSend serializedSize]; 

   if(s<128){
      NSLog(@"<128");
      NSData *size = [NSData dataWithBytes:&s length:1]; 
      [socket writeData:size withTimeout:TIME_OUT tag:100];
      [socket writeData:d withTimeout:TIME_OUT tag:101];
   } else {
     NSLog(@">= 128");
     NSData *size = [NSData dataWithBytes:&s length:2]; 
     [socket writeData:size withTimeout:TIME_OUT tag:100];
     [socket writeData:d withTimeout:TIME_OUT tag:101];
   }
}
```

I know the above is very wrong (just my hack attempt at understanding it all).  I don't know how to get `NSData *size` the correct length for messages over 128 in size.  I think it's something to do with Variants

Does anyone know how to do this? as it's driving me insane.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that `[NSData dataWithBytes:&s length:1]` and `[NSData dataWithBytes:&s length:2]` is not doing what you expecting. For example lets say you have your variable `s` equal to the hex value `0xFFCCAA00`. Passing a length of one means the size of the data will be one byte. Passing 1 your size will be equal to 0xFF (255) and passing 2 your size will be equal to 0xFFCC (65484). What you are probably looking for is the following

```
// >= 128
int length = 2;
NSData *size = [NSData dataWithBytes:&length length:sizeof(length)];
```

**Update:**

If you would like to send a single byte over try the following:

```
unsigned char length = 1;
// < 128
NSData *size = [NSData dataWithBytes:&length length:sizeof(length)];
// >= 128
length = 2;
NSData *size = [NSData dataWithBytes:&length length:sizeof(length)];
```

Comment: I think this is 1/2 the battle.  It has something to do with Variant under the GBP - see the following (see the Base 128 Variant section):

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html

Comment: Well according to that documentation the code I supplied is sufficient, if sending the length is affected by the encoding variants a then length of 2 is small enough to not need to set the msb I will update my post to show an example. If this question helped you send the correct length over let me know by telling me and/or accepting the answer :). If you have trouble writing the actual data over because of variants start another question with example code, feel free to post a link to it here so I can take a look at it.

Comment: Hi, But the above doesn't really make sense.
if s = 127 then accoridng to the doc it's one byte
if s = 129 then it will be two bytes

But the above Update doesn't send s, it only sends the length...

I'm confused by the above basically :(

Comment: I am not experienced with Google's buffer protocol but I do not think that you need to worry about that. From the looks of it the serialize method will take care of all the encoding for you and contain the necessary information to transport your data. The receiving end can then just deserialized that data. I see that you are writing the data to a socket, where are you trying to send it? Custom code on a server or another device?